# Is it possible to render your data using an html template before displaying the data from DB in Eve

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, eve

I am developing a simple API using Eve, to display the data from my Database on the web client using Eve, just following  the quickstart guide in Eve documents to write a schema and defining the resource in DOMAIN in settings.py, I can see the data in xml on a browser or using curl.

https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#a-more-complex-application

The data we see, (in the peoples eg) is either json/xml, for e.g: in json output:

```
{
    "firstname": "barack",
    "lastname": "obama",
    "_id": "50acfba938345b0978fccad7"
    "updated": "Wed, 21 Nov 2012 16:04:56 GMT",
    "created": "Wed, 21 Nov 2012 16:04:56 GMT",
    "_links": {
        "self": {"href": "people/50acfba938345b0978fccad7", "title": "person"},
        "parent": {"href": "/", "title": "home"},
        "collection": {"href": "people", "title": "people"}
    }
}
```

How can I change the html formatting of this data, using a template? For instance I want to create a table and display each item as a row in the table? Is there a way we can render this data using a Jinja templates by using event hooks?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better use Django, because in the definition o `eve`:

> Eve is an open source Python REST API framework designed for human beings. It allows to effortlessly build and deploy highly customizable, fully featured RESTful Web Services.

It's created for `RESTful` purposes.